# Disparador de UPDATE mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema: Necesito hacer un disparador que me actualice toda la fila con los nuevos datos, sin que esta me genere una nueva fila

Tengo este disparador que si inserta los datos pero me genera una fila nueva por cada actualizacion que genero.

```
Tiempo: AFTER
Evento: UPDATE

INSERT INTO switchs(id,clave,site,centro,marca,modelo,descripcion,npe,npg,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,e10,e11,e12,e13,e14,e15,e16,e17,e18,e19,e20,e21,e22,e23,e24,e25,e26,e27,e28,e29,e30,e31,e32,e33,e34,e35,e36,e37,e38,e39,e40,e41,e42,e43,e44,e45,e46,e47,e48,g1,g2,g3,g4)
VALUES (NEW.id,NEW.clave,NEW.site,NEW.centro,NEW.marca,NEW.modelo,NEW.descripcion,NEW.npe,NEW.npg,NEW.e1,NEW.e2,NEW.e3,NEW.e4,NEW.e5,NEW.e6,NEW.e7,NEW.e8,NEW.e9,NEW.e10,NEW.e11,NEW.e12,NEW.e13,NEW.e14,NEW.e15,NEW.e16,NEW.e17,NEW.e18,NEW.e19,NEW.e20,NEW.e21,NEW.e22,NEW.e23,NEW.e24,NEW.e25,NEW.e26,NEW.e27,NEW.e28,NEW.e29,NEW.e30,NEW.e31,NEW.e32,NEW.e33,NEW.e34,NEW.e35,NEW.e36,NEW.e37,NEW.e38,NEW.e39,NEW.e40,NEW.e41,NEW.e42,NEW.e43,NEW.e44,NEW.e45,NEW.e46,NEW.e47,NEW.e48,NEW.g1,NEW.g2,NEW.g3,NEW.g4)
```

Comment: si estas usando la misma tabla vas a crear un ciclo mortal en las inserciones

Comment: No,, de una tabla llamada switch1 se dispara a la tabla switchs

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla switchs?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un trigger para esto, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER foo AFTER UPDATE ON bar
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE bar SET updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = NEW.id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Para mayor información, puedes [ver esta documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).